# IE issues z-index css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I am utterly confused. I have read thru the articles recommended for this topic and still can't seem to find something that works.

Here's how it's SUPPOSED to look:
------> use FIRFOX or SAFARI
http://lisareisman.com/tests/focusTest

then look at it on IE 8 or 9. the 2 'i' icons and the iPod label have been 'relocated'.

this is the css:

```
#feature_top, feature_bottom {
z-index:1;
}

#feature_top img.info_btn {
position:relative;
float:right;
margin-top:-28px;
margin-right:165px;
z-index:2;
}

.img_overlay {
float:right;
margin-right:-15px;
margin-top: -150px;
position:relative;
z-index:3;
}

#feature_bottom img.info_btn {
position:relative;
float:right;
margin-top:-155px;
margin-right:125px;
z-index:2;
}
```

i have a separate ie style sheet.

html for the top section:

```
        <div id="feature_top">
        <img class="feature_arrow" src="img/arrow.png" alt="Feature arrow" />
            <h2>QwickPay Mobile Payment System</h2>
            <p class="top"><span class="bold">QwikPay</span> is a complete payment solution allowing your PC, Mac, IiPhone, iPod Touch, iPad or any other mobile smart phone, to evolve into a highly secure payment system. With <span class="bold">QwikPay</span>, you can easily accept credit and signature debit sales anytime, anyplace. Don't type, safely swipe and you and your customer will enjoy the convenience and peace of mind unmatched by any other secure, POS system. It is easy to use and can help merchants lower their cost of accepting cards by as much as 30%. When your customers want to pay with a card, <span class="bold">QwikPay</span> is the safest way.</p>
        <div id="feature1_img">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/qwikPaywithPhone.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="iframe" href="http://www.qwickpay.com/"><img class="info_btn" src="img/info_icon.png" /></a>
            <img class="img_overlay" src="img/made-for-iphone-ipod.png" />
            <div style="display: none;">
                  <a class="fancybox" href="img/setUpSale.png"></a>
            </div><!--end fancy box-->
        </div><!--end feature image 1-->
      </div><!--end of feature_top-->
```

I sure appreciate the help. I am close to wits end. I am using the Explorer Developer bar and I am trying to nudge the 'i' icons & the iPod label down and they get close then jump down past the image below.

I keep going back and trying things in other posts being suggested but can't seem to find the right one. Really appreciate the time. Have a good one!!

Thank you!!!

Lisa
'I should know how, but I don't' l;o)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using IE conditional comments in your CSS. Put them at the end of your current CSS declarations just in case (precedence)...

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
position:absolute
top:...px
left:...px

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!!!i used this on each image and it worked!! wow. so simple!!